# mongoose-paginate not working inside statics

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to use
`mongoose-paginate`  inside `statics` method, but it throws

> TypeError: this.paginate is not a function\n

I'm on node v10.0.0

```
"mongoose": "^4.9.7",
 mongoose-paginate": "^5.0.3",
```

Below is my code, what am I missing?

```
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");
    var CarSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
          showroom: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            index: true
          },
          doors: {
            type: String,
            required: true
          }});
    var paginate = require('mongoose-paginate');
    CarSchema.plugin(paginate); 

CarSchema.statics = {
  list({ page = 1, perPage = 30, name, email, role }) {
    const options = omitBy({ name, email, role }, isNil);
    // this.paginate is undefined here
    return this.paginate(options)
      .sort({ createdAt: -1 })
      .skip(perPage * (page - 1))
      .limit(perPage)
      .exec();
  }
```